# Doughnut chart plot area shrinks on its whim dynamically

Tags: excel, vba, excel-charts

I know I am making a mistake somewhere but I don't know where. Let me explain my problem.

So, I have a table with data for the charts like below:

[image]

The vba code will dynamically generate charts like below:

[image]

However, as I change the "% Done" values in column B in the table, and generate the charts, for some reason, the plot area is getting shrunk and the doughnut size increasing randomly.
[image]

Here is the code I have:

> ```
> Sub TeamStatsReport()
>
>
> Dim iStart As Integer, iSprintCount As Integer, iProgramIncrement As Integer, iSprint As Integer
> Dim bLoop As Boolean, bSprintFound As Boolean, bActiveSprint As Boolean, bFutureSprint As Boolean
> Dim sCurrentSprint As String, sNextSprint As String, sCurrentSprintID As String, sNextSprintID As String, sActiveSprint As String
> Dim Counter As Long, ws As Worksheet, zChartSet As ChartObject, colPos As Long, rowNumber As Long
>
> j = 4
> Set SprintsDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
> Set ws = ActiveSheet
>
> Const numChartsPerRow = 4
> Const TopAnchor As Long = 8
> Const LeftAnchor As Long = 450
> Const HorizontalSpacing As Long = 3
> Const VerticalSpacing As Long = 3
> Const ChartHeight As Long = 115
> Const ChartWidth As Long = 170
> Counter = 0
>
>
>
> For Each zChartSet In ws.ChartObjects
>     zChartSet.Delete
> Next zChartSet
>
> While j < 12
>     ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(251, xlDoughnut).Select
>     ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Worksheets("Infra Team Stats_").Range("B" & j & ":C" & j)
>     ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Select
>     ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Delete
>     ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
>     ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Name = "=""series1"""
>     ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = "={1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1}"
>          
>          
>     ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Select
>     Selection.Caption = Worksheets("Infra Team Stats_").Range("A" & j) & " - " & Format(Worksheets("Infra Team Stats_").Range("B" & j), "0%")
>
>
>     ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Select  
>     ActiveChart.ChartGroups(1).DoughnutHoleSize = 40
>
>     ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Select
>     With Selection.Format.Fill
>         .Visible = msoTrue
>         .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorBackground1
>         .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
>         .ForeColor.Brightness = -0.0500000007
>         .Solid
>     End With
>
>     With Selection.Format.Fill
>         .Visible = msoTrue
>         .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorAccent1
>         .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
>         .ForeColor.Brightness = -0.5
>         .Transparency = 0
>         .Solid
>     End With
>     
>     ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Select
>     Application.CutCopyMode = False
>     Application.CutCopyMode = False
>     ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
>     ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Name = Worksheets("Infra Team Stats_").Range("A" & j)
>     ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Values = Worksheets("Infra Team Stats_").Range("B" & j & ":C" & j)
>      
>     ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Select
>     ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).AxisGroup = 2
>      
>     ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Select
>     ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Points(1).Select
>     Selection.Format.Fill.Visible = msoFalse
>      
>     ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Select
>     ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Points(2).Select
>     With Selection.Format.Fill
>         .Visible = msoTrue
>         .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorBackground1
>         .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
>         .ForeColor.Brightness = -0.0500000007
>         .Transparency = 0
>         .Solid
>     End With
>     With Selection.Format.Fill
>         .Visible = msoTrue
>         .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorBackground1
>         .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
>         .ForeColor.Brightness = 0
>         .Transparency = 0.1999999881
>         .Solid
>     End With
>     ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementLegendNone)
>     
>     ActiveChart.PlotArea.Select
>     Selection.Width = 220
>     Selection.Height = 120
>     With ActiveChart
>      .PlotArea.Left = (.ChartArea.Width - .PlotArea.Width) / 2
>      .PlotArea.Top = (.ChartArea.Height - .PlotArea.Height) / 2
>     End With
>
>     j = j + 1
> Wend
>
> For Each zChartSet In ws.ChartObjects
>     rowNumber = Int(Counter / numChartsPerRow)
>     colPos = Counter Mod numChartsPerRow
>
>     With zChartSet
>         .Top = TopAnchor + rowNumber * (VerticalSpacing + ChartHeight)
>         .Left = LeftAnchor + colPos * (HorizontalSpacing + ChartWidth)
>         .Height = ChartHeight
>         .Width = ChartWidth
>     End With
>
>     Counter = Counter + 1
> Next zChartSet
> End Sub
> ```

Comment: A tip to save yourself a lot of problems later: save things into variables. `Set myChart = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(251, xlDoughnut)` and now you can use `myChart` instead of `ActiveChart` or `Selection`. This makes your code resistant to unintended objects being Active, and avoids situations where `Selection` isnt what you thought it would be. Same advice for any other use of `Select` and `Selection`.

Comment: So, the code is buggy after I made the changes you recommended. I added these two lines: ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(251, xlDoughnut).Select
        Set myChart = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(251, xlDoughnut). It is now erroring on myChart.SetSourceData Source:=Worksheets("Infra Team Stats_").Range("B" & j & ":C" & j)

Comment: [This may help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) for the avoidance of Select. For the chart size reduction, maybe reducing the width and height of the plot area (` .PlotArea.Left = (.ChartArea.Width - .PlotArea.Width) / 2` and `.PlotArea.Top = (.ChartArea.Height - .PlotArea.Height) / 2`) is the problem?

Comment: Can you adjust the code, please? I am not sure where to change.

Comment: @Jrules80 It doesn't need to be 2 lines, just one line `Set myChart = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(251, xlDoughnut)` (note that this line does not have `.Select`). This line creates the chart *and* saves it into variable `myChart`.

Comment: Thank for correcting, Toddleson. Even with just Set myChart = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(251, xlDoughnut), I am still not able to set the source data  to "myChart". It is failing here >> myChart.SetSourceData Source:=Worksheets("Infra Team Stats_").Range("B" & j & ":C" & j)

Answer (score 0):

The code works although it could be designed better, i.e. create all graphs the first time and then only the one whose data changes. It took some "tricks" to make it work. To take advantage of the plot's internal space we must first shrink the PlotArea and place it in the corner, then set one of its dimensions, because the other always follows the size automatically. Another inexplicable thing is that if you call TeamStatsReport through a Worksheet_Change then before the call we have to move the focus to a cell outside the data area because otherwise an error is generated.

```
'THIS CODE IN THE SHEET
Option Explicit

Private Sub TeamStatsReport()
   Dim J As Long, Counter As Long, colPos As Long, rowNumber As Long, cc As Integer
   Dim zChartSet As ChartObject
   
   Const numChartsPerRow = 4
   Const TopAnchor As Long = 8
   Const LeftAnchor As Long = 200
   Const HorizontalSpacing As Long = 3
   Const VerticalSpacing As Long = 3
   Const ChartHeight As Long = 130
   Const ChartWidth As Long = 110
   
   On Error GoTo Lerr
   Application.Interactive = False
   Counter = 0
   J = 4
   
   For Each zChartSet In Me.ChartObjects
       zChartSet.Delete
   Next zChartSet
   
   While J < 12
   ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(251, xlDoughnut).Select
      With ActiveChart
         .ChartArea.Height = ChartHeight
         .ChartArea.Width = ChartWidth
         .SetSourceData Source:=Me.Range("B" & J & ":C" & J)
         .FullSeriesCollection(1).Select
         .FullSeriesCollection(1).Delete
         .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
         .FullSeriesCollection(1).Name = "=""series1"""
         .FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = "={1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1}"
         '.ChartTitle.Select
         .ChartTitle.Caption = Me.Range("A" & J) & " - " & Format(Me.Range("B" & J), "0%")
         .FullSeriesCollection(1).Select
      End With
      With Selection.Format.Fill
         .Visible = msoTrue
         .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorAccent1
         .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
         .ForeColor.Brightness = -0.5
         .Transparency = 0
         .Solid
      End With
   
      ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
      With ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2)
         .Name = Me.Range("A" & J)
         .Values = Me.Range("B" & J & ":C" & J)
         '.Select
         .AxisGroup = 2
         '.Select
         .Points(1).Select
         Selection.Format.Fill.Visible = msoFalse
         .Points(2).Select
      End With
      
      With Selection.Format.Fill
         .Visible = msoTrue
         .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorBackground1
         .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
         .ForeColor.Brightness = 0
         .Transparency = 0.1999999881
         .Solid
      End With
      
      With ActiveChart
         .SetElement (msoElementLegendNone)
         .PlotArea.Select
         .PlotArea.Left = 1
         .PlotArea.Top = 1
         .PlotArea.Width = 1
         .PlotArea.Height = (.ChartArea.Height * 0.99) - .ChartTitle.Height
         .PlotArea.Left = (.ChartArea.Width - .PlotArea.Width) / 2
         .PlotArea.Top = (.ChartArea.Height - .PlotArea.Height + .ChartTitle.Height) / 2
      End With
      
      J = J + 1
   Wend

   For Each zChartSet In Me.ChartObjects
      rowNumber = Int(Counter / numChartsPerRow)
      colPos = Counter Mod numChartsPerRow
      
      With zChartSet
         .Top = TopAnchor + rowNumber * (VerticalSpacing + ChartHeight)
         .Left = LeftAnchor + colPos * (HorizontalSpacing + ChartWidth)
         .Height = ChartHeight
         .Width = ChartWidth
         For cc = 1 To .Chart.ChartGroups.Count
            .Chart.ChartGroups(cc).DoughnutHoleSize = linear_interpolation(280, 75, 85, 46, minOf(.Chart.ChartArea.Width, .Chart.ChartArea.Height))
         Next
      End With
      Counter = Counter + 1
   Next zChartSet
Lerr:
   On Error GoTo 0
   Application.Interactive = True
   Me.Range("A1").Select
End Sub


Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   If Not Intersect(Target, Range("LDATA")) Is Nothing Then
   'next line is critical. If don't move selection out of the
   'SourceData  (.SetSourceData Source:=Me.Range("B" & J & ":C" & J))
   'the code in the TeamStatsReport Sub generates an error
      Me.Range("A1").Select
      Call TeamStatsReport
      Target.Select
   End If
End Sub


'AND THIS IN A MODULE
Public Function minOf(a As Variant, b As Variant) As Variant
   If (a < b) Then minOf = a Else minOf = b
End Function

Public Function linear_interpolation(x1 As Double, y1 As Double, x2 As Double, y2 As Double, ByVal x As Double) As Double
   If (x2 - x1) = 0 Then   'division by zero
      linear_interpolation = 0#  'or anything else...maybe y1 or y2 ...
   Else
      linear_interpolation = y1 + (((x - x1) * (y2 - y1)) / (x2 - x1))
   End If
End Function

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
   'you need the next line.The selected cell must be outside the data area, otherwise an error occurs
   Me.Range("A1").Select  'A1 or any cell out of the data range
   Call TeamStatsReport
End Sub
```

[image]

I WROTE IN HEADER OF ANSWER: THIS CODE IN THE SHEET
Copy TeamStatsReport in the Sheet's module NO IN MODULE3 or any other. Take a look in the code above how to modify the CommandButton1_Click...

Comment: I am calling this sub-routine via a click of a command button (activeX). Also, running this code is erroring. It says "Invalid use of Me keyword"

Comment: Put the sub in the sheets module where is the button. The Me means the sheet where the code exists. In the sheet whwre create the graphs

Comment: So... The Button calls  >>  Private Sub CommandButton1_Click() >> calls f_InfraTeamStats.TeamStatsReport >> Private Sub TeamStatsReport.

Comment: I put your code in the "module" and I still get the error

Comment: can you send me the all code calling the TeamStatsReport. And in whith sheet is the button, in whitch the TeamStatsReport and in whitch you want to create the charts?

Comment: OK so, I have a worksheet named "Infra Team Stats". In the worksheet, I have a button and upon clicking the button, it calls this >> Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
 Module3.TeamStatsReport
End Sub. And I have module named "Module3" and inside it, there is a sub-routine called TeamStatsReport which is where the code that I posted in the question resides.